# How can i change the database of my meteor app

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have my meteor app using the database named 'meteor'. (mongo db)

Now i decided to crate a new database named 'myNewDB' and new collections named.

Somehow i can not connect to this new database with my meteor app.

How can i configure my app to connect to new database instead of old one?

Answer (score 1):

You can start your meteor application providing a `MONGO_URL` environment variable where you can set a specific mongodb connection string:

```
MONGO_URL=mongodb://user:password@localhost:27017/yourDbName meteor
```

Meteor environment variables are listed [here](http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/Environment_Variables)

Comment: Normally when i type 'meteor' it starts up the database too. When i use your suggestion, should the db already be started up and running?

Comment: Yes, definitely. Your app won't be able to connect to the database if the mongo daemon is not up and running.

Comment: how can i start up my mongo deamon? It came bundled with meteor installation.

Comment: That kinda depends on your machine: [check this link](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes/)

Answer (score 0):

You can set up new database connection with MONGO_URL in environtment var

Comment: Can you explain more detailed if it is different than the answer above?